# Grep: separate output into two column and save them into txt file

Tags: bash, shell-script, output

In a directory, after running `ls -d -- 0.*_*.txt | sort -t. -k1`, I obtained output filenames such as

`0.230_0.203059.txt`

How can I further writing each of them into two columns like

`0.230 0.203059`

into a txt file?

Comment: Why are you sorting the filenames on the initial `0` specifically? Did you mean `sort -k2,2n -t.`?  What is the purpose of this exercise? There may be better ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some aversion against parsing the output of ls (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs among others), but that aside:

`ls -d -- 0.*_*.txt` I don't know why you put the `--` there; the `-d` just prevents you from descending into directories. In your set-up, you will probably need neither.

The `ls` will generate filenames such as `0.230_0.203059.txt`, so with the txt. You will need to strip that too.

```
ls 0.*_*.txt | sort -t. -k1 | sed 's/.txt//;s/_/ /' > outfile.txt
```

should do that.

Comment: yes, with the `.txt` I update my question